# How to create a new parent section on the Configuration page?

Tags: forms, 9

When one navigates to **Manage » Configuration**, the page is divided into sections which (in the "Seven" theme at least) shows up in individual boxes. These sections have headings like "People", "Content authoring", "Development", etc.

I am able to create a settings form and place this inside any of the existing sections on the configuration page by associating it with the `parent` key in `hello_world.links.menu.yml`.

Example:

```
hello_world.greeting_form:
  title: 'Salutation settings'
  description: 'Configure the salutation message.'
  route_name: hello_world.greeting_form
  parent: system.admin_config_development
```

This places a link to the settings form for the "Hello World" module in the "Development" section. This is not where I want to place it.

Instead, I want to create a new section named "Examples", place this new section along with the others on the "Configuration" page, and make this new section the parent of my link to the settings form.

Below is an image of what I want it to look like. There should be a new section, named "Examples" as the section heading, and in that section, there should be a link to the settings form with the text "Salutation settings":

[image]

Comment: if that is not the place you want the menu item. Can you share screen shot of where its needed so will update my answer.

Comment: No, that is not where I want it. I've added a screen shot as suggested to better show what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yaml-files that do this for the core is located in `core/modules/system/`. I eventually solved it by copying and adapting the relevant bits from `system.routing.yml`and `system.links.menu.yml`.

First, in `hello_world.routing.yml`, set up the routings we shall need:

```
hello_world.admin_config_examples:
  path: '/admin/config/examples'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
    _title: 'Examples'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access administration pages'

hello_world.greeting_form:
  path: '/admin/config/examples/salutation-configuration'
  defaults:
    _form: Drupal\hello_world\Form\SalutationConfigurationForm
    _title: 'Salutation configuration'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

Then, in `hello_world.links.menu.yml`, set up menu items. First the item that is going to be link to the section, and then the the menu item that links to the settings form:

```
hello_world.admin_config_examples:
  title: 'Examples'
  route_name: hello_world.admin_config_examples
  parent: system.admin_config
  weight: 0
hello_world.greeting_form:
  title: 'Salutation settings'
  description: 'Configure the salutation message.'
  route_name: hello_world.greeting_form
  parent: hello_world.admin_config_examples
```

Comment: you beat me here. yes, that was exact change `system.admin_config` . Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it.

#example_codes.links.menu.yml

```
example_codes.base:
  title: 'Example Codes Module'
  parent: system.admin
  description: 'A Module with various Examples.'
  route_name: example_codes.base
  weight: 0
```

You need to define `system.admin` as parent.

And in your routing.yml should contain this base route.

#example_codes.routing.yml

```
example_codes.base:
  path: '/admin/examples-codes'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
    _title: 'Example Codes Module'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer example codes configurations'
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time answering. Your code works, but places the link alongside "Configuration" within the admin toolbar. I want a new section to appear on the "Configuration" page. I've added a mock-up image of what it is I try to achieve.